# ASFolder String for Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" returning Run-Time '91'

Tags: excel, vba

I am building fairly complex accounting suite for an accountant and I don't quite understand why each time file changes folder I encounter this error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

Code:

```
Public Function ASFolder() As String
Dim ASwb As Workbook: Set ASwb = ThisWorkbook
If ASwb.Sheets(1).Range("B8").Value = "A" Then   'file path detection
ASFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" < < < WHERE ERROR 91 IS INDICATED.
Else
ASFolder = ASwb.Sheets(1).Range("B8").Value & "\"
End If
End Function
```

There is code that is being launched upon file opening. Could this be related?

Purpose is simple: when file is being open detect certain settings within the document and perform desired actions accordingly - therefore this setting is of significant importance to me.

There is no issues with this until I change folder for the file, as if first file opening does something unusual or something I don't understand.

Greatly appreciated any suggestions.

Comment: `when file is being open` At that time most probably there is no activeworkbook and hence you get the error. Change it to `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" `

Comment: Can't mark your comment but yes...that was the problem thank you so much @SiddharthRout <facepalm>